# Execute "delete all" before processing - Spring Integration Usage

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm building a Spring Boot app that watches a folder in a file system. When a new file shows up, the file should be parsed and saved to a database. The file will be processed line by line and each line will be saved as a new record. There is a scenario when I should FIRST delete all records from the table and then start to insert them. I was recommended to use Spring Integration. Is this a good fit for this? If so, what is the best way to achieve the scenario with "delete all"?

Answer (score 1):

Add a bean that implements `SmartLifecycle` then; in the `start()` method use a `JdbcTemplate.execute()` to truncate the table.